# How to Access a Global Temporary Tables from Excel and Other Applications

Tags: excel, sybase, temp-tables, sqlanywhere

We are trying to access a temporary table that is generated by SQL Anywhere in excel and some other applications.  When the database information populates in Microsoft Query and Database Tools none of the temporary tables are visible.

I've tried running a query on the table itself and it returns no data, however when one of our software packages with an inbuilt connection connects to the same temporary table it populates the last two rows in the queue.  I've tried to create a view of the table and it returns no data as well.  This is my first time working with global temporary tables and I'm wondering how external applications are able to connect and pull the data.

```
SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
```

This returns no results but the table structure. Though at some point this table is generated and either maintains the data in memory or in some other way as one of our applications has an inbuilt connection that is reading that data.

How does one connect to and draw data from a global temporary table in SQLAnywhere/MSSQL?

Comment: That is NOT a global temp table. It is a persistent table.

Comment: Then why does it say "Global temporary table" in the type column in Sybase Central?

Comment: In sql server that is NOT a global temp table. I can't tell you about sybase. Need to be careful when tagging to tag only the DBMS you are working with.

Comment: I adjusted the tags, though afaik SQLAnywhere and MSSQL share their origin and there is a lot of similarity and overlap.  BTW if you read my first sentence you would be aware that I was using SQLAnywhere, and I have no idea how you would know whether or not a table is, in fact, a global temporary table or not by what I had written.

Comment: In sql server a global temp table would be ##tmp_table. A local temp table would be #tmp_table. And a persistent table would be as you posted yours. Hope that helps clarify how I could tell.

Comment: Yes, that does clarify, thank you!